# Back button is not working properly in Right side of action bar

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to just add back button in Right side of action bar and I found many link for this.

This is my code which is app->res->menu->main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
android:id="@+id/backAction"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:title="back"
android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Optionmenuactivity.java

Oncreate event:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

onoptionItemselected()

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.backAction:
            this.finish();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Manifest File :

```
 <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value="com.example.app.MainActivity" />
```

Problem with this code:

Activity Flow is: (Main)Activity1-> Activity2 ->Activity3 ->Activity4

after Activity4, if we press backbutton, it should go on Activity3 but with this code it goes Mainactivity which is Activity1

Please help me ..Thank you

Comment: How you start Activity?

Comment: why are you finishing instead call onBackPressed()
 case R.id.backAction:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i wanted to say what you are trying to do is not a good practice, why would you want a back button in your action bar if Android devices already have one on the bottom of the screen and you can turn on Up-Navigation at the left side of the Action Bar?

Custom App-Navigation clutters your code, confuses users and most of the time is just ugly.

But if you really need a button that does the navigation, you want it to access the standard android navigation methods.

**For Back Navigation:**

Just use the standard android back action [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()).

```
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

   if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.backAction:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

 }
```

If this function doesn't do what you want, you can just override it with your own wanted behavior.

**For Up Navigation:**

```
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

   if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.backAction:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

 }
```

You will have to configure your parent activites in the manifest, but because of that the behavior of this Navigation is easier to change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as client want that thats why I want to do it..and one more question: Should I add <meta-data> in manifest or not?

Comment: The other answer is very helpful also. Try to read up on Up/Back Navigation, decide which is one is more suited for your case. In case you want to use Up Navigation, you have to add parent activity meta data.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of problems here.

Firstly I recommend you, to understand the difference between Back and Up

[Up navigation explained with examples](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)
[Back navigation explained with examples](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html)

Secondly, it's not very easy to understand what's happening in your code, but as far as I see, you HAVE NOT declared in the manifest.xml the parent elements.

This is a nice and simple example:

```
    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
```

A parent activity definition can EASE your life. This way you can define which activity will be loaded on UP NAVIGATION interaction.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I already go through this , Here I have edited my question please refer that..Only problem with this code is it doesn't go in previous screen , It directly go through Main(home)Screen..and I dont want that output..Please give me appropriate solution..Thank you

Comment: Vidhi, I think that you don't get my idea.

Every activity must have this <metadata> tag and there you must specify that e.g. Activity 4 has parent Activity 3; Activity 3 has parent activity 2 and so on.

In addition, you can check if you are not just finish()-ing these activities and when Up button tries to do his job, the activities are no longer available and that's why it opens Activity 1 :)

Comment: Yes..got it..Thanks a ton @stuci..i really understood new thing today..Actually I am totally new in android development..Thax once again :)

Comment: No problems :) feel free to ask and btw mark the question/answer as Answered so the community can check this out too :)